# Why am I getting an 'unexpected return' error after a conditional?

Tags: javascript, eslint

```
const result = 2

function dothis() {
    const number = 5

    if (number < 0) {
      result == 0 ? console.log('error')
      return false
    }
}
```

Why is this code giving an "unexpected return" error?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: `condition ? expr1 : expr2 ` <- Look at your code and look at this reference. See any problems?

Comment: where is result defined here and where is the else statement ?

Answer (score 1):

When using ternary condition you need to use the syntax `condition?statement:statement`. Thus, you are missing the third part, the `statement`, hence the name implies `ternary`(three parts).

```js
var results = [];
function dothis() {
    const number = -1;
    if (number < 0) {
      results.length == 0 ? console.log('error'): console.log('no error');
      return false
    }
}
dothis();
```

Comment: So, I can't use a ternary without an 'else' statement?  That was what I was going for.

Comment: @DavidWaters  Looks like your after an if statement,  `if (!results.length) console.log('error')`

Comment: I was trying to do:
    if (results.length) { console.log('error') }
    return false

Comment: I thought I could use the ternary '?' in the same way as 'if' and not have to have the ': else' part

Answer (score 1):

I found out that your conditional if else shorthand is not completed, Else part is missing there.

```js
function dothis() {
    const number = 5

    if (number > 0) {
      results.length == 0 ? console.log('error') : console.log ('success')
      return false
    }
}
```

this will complete your condition. Please let me know if you are trying to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing *:*

```
results.length == 0 ? console.log('error') : console.log('success')
```